# Select from a nvarchar(max) column in SQL Server returns the value truncated

Tags: sql-server, odbc, powerbuilder

I select from a column declared as `nvarchar(max)` from a table in SQL Server using an odbc connection (even with a native driver).

The result from the select is truncated if the value in the column has more than 32676 character.

I use a Power Builder application. I'm able to write the right value with the same application.

Comment: This likely depends on which version of PB you are using and the type of connection.

Comment: Maybe this [appeon form link](https://community.appeon.com/index.php/qna/q-a/powerbuilder-2017-r3-sql-server-nvarchar-max-cut-after-32766-characters) helps